# Mount and unlock encrypted Tryecrypt drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, encryption

I have encrypted the whole disk using Truecrypt under Windows. My Windows 7 OS suffers from some software failure and I need to reinstall the OS, but I need to backup my personal data first. I can boot using an Ubuntu Live CD, but how should I unlock my drive?
Edit: I found out that Truecrypt supports CLI. Correct me if I'm wrong: 
`truecrypt /q /v /mnt/sda1`

Comment: Off-topic for SO, voting to move to SuperUser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've encrypted this partition as a system drive, you'll need to mount it with system encryption without pre-boot authentication. This is available in the GUI using *Volumes -> Mount Volumes with Options* on Windows (but it might not be available with the Linux GUI).

If you want to do with on the command line, you'll have to find the equivalent on the [`/m sm` option on Windows](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=command-line-usage) (note that this page is for the Windows CLI, the Linux version varies slightly, use `truecrypt --help`). Although there doesn't seem to be details about the possible values for `-m`, the following should work:

```
truecrypt -m system /dev/sda1
```

Comment: I cannot access Windows anymore, so I need to fire up Ubuntu. It's a complete disk encryption. Thank you for your effort! I'll reply back!